# Getting url errors after deployment

Tags: django, nginx

Hello I have a django project with the domain [www.itucampus.com](http://www.itucampus.com), I owned the domain from godaddy and forwarded itucampus.com to [www.itucampus.com](http://www.itucampus.com) I hosted it on pythonanywhere.com. I also forced http to https. My problem now is sometimes I could reach my webpage and sometimes not and now I found which urls are working and which not.

itucampus.com [www.itucampus.com](http://www.itucampus.com) https://www.itucampus.com are working

but

https://itucampus.com http://itucampus.com http://www.itucampus.com are not working and I am getting the error to many redirects.

Could you please help me

Comment: What is your server stack, are you using APACHE or NGINX?

Comment: I am using nginx

Comment: Please post your config files.

Comment: which config do you mean

Comment: in your machine it will be located somewhere like /etc/nginx/conf.d/itucampus.com.conf

Comment: I think there's a little bit of confusion here -- PythonAnywhere does use nginx under the hood, but those config files are not editable.

Answer (score 0):

GoDaddy doesn't support HTTPS-based redirects, so if you want `https://itucampus.com` to work, you'll need to use a different service for your redirects.  [NakedSSL](https://www.nakedssl.com/) is a free one that should work well.